# How to redirect http request to a different URL with nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, redirect, forwarding

I need to redirect following URL:

http://www.example.com/product/product-name/1234

to

http://www.example.com/details/product.jsp?pid=1234

Can somebody help me on this? We are using nginx 1.1.19. Also, we need a server side redirect (URL in client side's browser should stay as the first one), not an http forward.

Thanks.

==============  add more information for debugging:

In the details/product.jsp file, I have something like this:

```
<link href="../docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And the bootstrap.css is under /usr/share/nginx/www/docs/assets/css/ . However, when I use rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/product/product-name/(\d+)$ /details/product.jsp?pid=$1;
```

The root directory somehow become /www/product, hence the details/product.jsp tries to find the bootstrap.css under:

```
/usr/share/nginx/www/product/docs/assets/css
```

which causes file not found error in the log.

Hope above information helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd done some basic searching you would have found the [nginx rewrite module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule), which provides the `rewrite` directive.

```
rewrite ^/product/product-name/(\d+)$ /details/product.jsp?pid=$1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this changed URL in client side browser. We want the URL to stay unchanged for users. Anyway I can do that?

Comment: You used the rule exactly as above? nginx should only redirect if the replacement is an absolute URL or the `permanent` or `redirect` flags are added. Are you sure that nginx is redirecting and not the product.jsp script?

Comment: Sorry I just tried again and actually got some error in nginx log: `*1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/product/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.2.3, server: localhost, request: "GET /product/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.taggto.com/product/product-name/1234"` I noticed nginx got the root path wrong in this case: the css file is under directory /www, but it is looking for it under /www/product.

Comment: @YuchenWang Your HTML is referencing a non-existent file.

Comment: @ngorven, thanks for helping out. I just updated the question, hope it gives more information to debug.